# What happens to the Bottom Layout Guide when an InputView is displayed (i.e. keyboard)

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, keyboard, resize, inputview

So everyone loves this new Layout semantics in storyboard, it's dynamic in a way it adapts at runtime when we're inside a UINavigationController for example.

Now what about inputViews? I know inputViews are NOT part of my view, but wouldn't it make sense to affect the bottom layout guide of the containing view when a keyboard is displayed?

I mean, I've seen several coding solutions to this issue, but only one affectively takes advantage of the bottom layout guide (the others are deprecated or plain simple wrong approaches), but even that one sounds hard-wacky-coding and naturally it doesn't animate.

Is there a way to tell the view to adjust the bottom layout guide for input views automatically? I mean in storyboard? or do we need to do this sucky code let every time we use a keyboard in our application?

If the Keyboard appearing animated:YES would affect the bottom layout guide in it's progress we'd have yet another apple-is-so-cool-they-make-all-the-hard-work-for-us-while-enforcing-their-user-interface-guidelines....aff that was long :)

Comment: I think you're absolutely right and have submitted rdar://19933048 for this